# Wireshark does not open URLs in GET requests anymore

Tags: debian, wireshark

Since a few days my Wireshark does not seem to open URL anymore, when I double click them in the corresponding section in the GET request packet. Instead, it gets copied to the clipboard. As I have to open a lot of URL per day, this is quite annoying. Does anyone know a fix for this?

- OS: Debian Bullseye amd64
- Package: https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-click was ruled out as a security risk.

Read the article
[Pwning the pen tester: Malicious Wireshark packet capture file risk revealed](https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/pwning-the-pen-tester-malicious-wireshark-packet-capture-file-risk-revealed):

> Maliciously constructed Wireshark packet capture files might be used
> to distribute malware, providing recipients can be **tricked into double
> clicking file URL fields**.
>
> Variants of the same attack could potentially be thrown against users
> of the popular network security tool, widely used by security analysts
> and penetration testers, whether they use Windows or Xubuntu
> Linux-based systems.

This is by design, and probably cannot be undone.
The only possibility I can see is to use
an older Wireshark version that does not yet have this feature.

Comment: Wow... I knew that Debian is a tad slow applying new versions but...